# How to determine entity relationship? How to differ between one to many and many to many

Tags: entity-relationship

I have two entity sets Consultant and Answer. I can't define their relationship, like consultant can give many answers, and answers could be written by many consultants . Or its like consultant can write many answers, and the answers could be written by only one consultant (like, there's only one author of the answer)
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your post to include an actual question you want to ask.

Comment: Looks like you already know the technical difference between them. The answer of your question depends on your business requirements.